# Create custom search module and display results in custom component

Tags: php, joomla, module, components

In the context of a larger project, I have created a Joomla 1.5 component that formats and displays information received from a web service. Now I need to use a search module, to filter what is displayed. There is already a second web service that returns filtered results.

So my idea is to use a module like the default search module, if possible. The user types in the keywords, and when he hits "ok" these are sent to my component somehow. Then the component reads this info and knows that it needs to call the search web service with the keywords as parameters. Note that I need this search functionality only to the one page where this component is used.

What is the best way to achieve a similar result?

Comment: i think a plugin will help you that you want. hope this link will help you http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin#Search

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know that a plugin will do something when an event is received, but how will it send the information to the component? And how do I force this to happen only on that specific page? Needless to say I 'm a beginner in the Joomla framework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All informations, data results are shown on the main area. So your module search results simply need links to your search component! Ex :

```
index.php?option=com_mycompname&view=application&Itemid=114&q=user+search+query
```